# Symbol levels: difference between layer numbers and values in the columns

Tags: qgis

Can anyone explain in words the difference between the layer numbers ("layer 0", "layer 1"...) and the values in the columns for symbol levels, or point me to where I can find this? That is, what they mean in terms of what gets drawn in what order. The text in the Desktop User Guide (below) doesn't explain it; I spent an hour on trial-and-error changing the values using the dedicated portion of the Training Manual and its sample data and still don't get it. What I'm looking for is verbal explanation.

> The numbers represent the rendering order level in which the symbol layer will be drawn. Lower values levels are drawn first, staying at the bottom, while higher values are drawn last, on top of the others.

*- Desktop User Guide  3.22 p.442 -*

Answer (score 0):

The interest of these levels is the management
intersections of multisymbol entities,
here (capture taken from a training I had) the line
red at level 3 will be continuous
whatever the intersections with a
another category, then the blue level line
2 will take precedence over levels
lower and so on.
When symbol levels are enabled, the
the elementary symbols are drawn in the order indicated:
-0: black line
-1: orange line
-2: blue line
-3: red line
[image]

When levels are not enabled,elementary symbols are displayed in an apparent mess, little visually satisfying.

[image]